# React Native build ios Flipper crash

Tags: ios, react-native, flipper

I don't know what changed but I tried just about any thing and I am always getting this message:

```
The following build commands failed:
    CompileC eveloper/Xcode/DerivedData/xxx-bvxasjfnemrqklbhzatwzolraqjj/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Flipper-Folly.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/DistributedMutex.o /WebstormProjects/xxx/ios/Pods/Flipper-Folly/folly/synchronization/DistributedMutex.cpp normal x86_64 c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
(1 failure)
```

This is my Podfile:

```
require_relative '../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'
permissions_path = '../node_modules/react-native-permissions/ios'

platform :ios, '10.0'

target 'xxx' do
  config = use_native_modules!

  use_react_native!(:path => config["reactNativePath"])



  pod 'RNSVG', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-svg'

  pod 'react-native-camera', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-camera'

  pod 'RNPermissions', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-permissions'

  pod 'Permission-Camera', :path => "#{permissions_path}/Camera"
  pod 'RNCPicker', :path => '../node_modules/@react-native-picker/picker'

  pod 'react-native-splash-screen', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-splash-screen'

  pod 'react-native-fbsdk', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-fbsdk'

  pod 'RNCAsyncStorage', :path => '../node_modules/@react-native-async-storage/async-storage'

  pod 'RNVectorIcons', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons'

  target 'xxxTests' do
    inherit! :complete
    # Pods for testing
  end

  # Enables Flipper.
  #
  # Note that if you have use_frameworks! enabled, Flipper will not work and
  # you should disable these next few lines.
  use_flipper!
  post_install do |installer|
    flipper_post_install(installer)
  end
end

target 'xxx-tvOS' do
  # Pods for xxx-tvOS

  target 'xxx-tvOSTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end
end
```

Some of the things I tried:

1. rm Pods + Podfile.lock and pod install
2. Setting flipper version 0.74.0
3. I am 100% sure I am opening the project with the `xcworkspace` and not the `xcodeproj`

Thanks to anyone who can help